# The minipage syntax

Tags: minipage

Can you explain me the syntax of the minipage please?

For example, here:

```
 \begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\linewidth}
```

what means 0.45 ?

Thank you in advance

**Edit:**

```
\documentclass{svjour3}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{latin1}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=3.2cm,left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm]{geometry}

% Citation of the figure 
is shown in \ref{fig:metal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
ff & ff   & ff & ff \\ \hline
dd & ddd  & ff & jj \\ \hline
ss & xxtt & l  & jj \\ \hline
hh & gg   & ll & ll \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\linewidth}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm,height=4.1cm]{Image.jpg}\label{fig:im1}}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\linewidth}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=11cm,height=6cm]{spectra.jpg}\label{fig:spectra}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% I would like to make the figure after 10 cm from the beginning of the line and not just after the `tabular`. What shall I do please?
\end{document}
```

Comment: that width of `minipage` is 45% of `linewidth`, i.e.: 0.45 is simple coefficient by which is multiplied `\linewidth`.

Comment: thank you for your response.  I still neeed a clarification.

Comment: If the line with is for example 16cm, and I  would to insert the figure or the table after 10cm, what shall I do ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. -- Your original question was pretty simple, but your second question in the comment is difficult to interpret. An MWE would help immensely here.

Comment: your comment above is not clear ... `minipage` after what? left text border? than `\hspace*{10cm}\begin{minipage}{4cm}`, if `minipage` width is 10 cm, than simple `\minipage{10cm}`.. please, provide mwe, that we can more clear see, what is your problem.

Comment: please find an example code below

Comment: @SeifFetni, i move code from your answer to question, where it belong. i find your code very erroneous, please make it compilable and correct it  (`\include graphics{}` is correct `\includegraphics{}` etc).

Answer (score 6):

in your mwe you have more issues:

- missing package `graphicx` in preamble
- missing is `\begin{document}`
- you have spelling error in include graphics: instead of `\include graphics{}` had to be `\includegraphics{}`
- if you like to have all three `minipage`s in one line, then the sum of their width should be equal or less of `\textwidth` or in your case of `linewidth`, now you have `0.5\linewidth` + `0.3\linewidth` + `0.45\linewidth` = `1.25\linewidth`, consequently third `minipage` is moved in the next line.

corrected your mwe with added `lipsum` for generating dummy text is:

```
\documentclass{article}%{svjour3}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\inputencoding{latin1}
%\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=3.2cm,left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% for including images

\usepackage{lipsum}% for demo only

\begin{document}
% Citation of the figure is shown in \ref{fig:metal}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
a & b & c
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics{}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
a & b & c
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

i use `article` because i haven't installed `svjour3`, however described issues are independent of used document class.

[image]